# How do I properly distribute dylib dependencies in a .app bundle on OSX?

Tags: c++, dependencies, software-distribution

Specifically, I'm trying to install glew and freetype. I've copied the .dylibs into the .app directory and set their paths with install_name_tool. When I try to run them on other machines I get the following error:

```
Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Resources/libGLEW.2.0.0.dylib
 Referenced from: /Volumes/*/Tetris.app/Contents/MacOS/Tetris
 Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /Volumes/SharedFolders/build/Tetris.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/libGLEW.2.0.0.dylib: stat() failed with errno=22
  /Volumes/SharedFolders/build/Tetris.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/libGLEW.2.0.0.dylib: stat() failed with errno=22
```

Comment: Have you considered placing the dynamic libraries in the same folder as the executable?

Comment: I tried placing them in the same directory and I got the same error.  It seems to be able to find the dylibs but there is something wrong with them.

Comment: Is there a general tutorial for distributing executables with dylibs?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue. The problem was that I ran install_name_tool on only the executable when I needed to run it on both the executable, with the `-change` switch, and the dylib, with the `-id` switch.

I've also discovered through doing this that the dylibs have other dylibs they depend on, which must, in turn, be copied into the bundle and reconfigured with install_name_tool.

If anyone knows of a tool which does all of this automatically, please leave a comment.